# Show Today in Agenda View even there is no event attached with "No event Created"

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I have one Android calendar with four View

- options:Week view, Month view, Day View and Agenda view.

  I want to show Today in the list of Agenda view even if there is no event Attached to Today. I have tried to check whether any event exist for today or not. But if i add extra data forcefully i get `nullpointer` exception. Below is the view of Calendar Agenda view.

I have one stickyheader listview to show list of events. Able to display all the days with event. But my question is : How to show Today even there is no event with "No event for today create now option".

Any help will be appreciated.

Have used https://github.com/Etar-Group/Etar-Calendar/tree/master/src/com/android/calendar/agenda for displaying and loading events.

[image: CalendarView]

Comment: Make recyclerview with multitype row to show list.

Comment: please provide your code here

Comment: show me where you get null pointer. put some code here, and stacktrace also..

Comment: you can make 2 adapter, 1 for event and second for no event, and make condition like if you got no event than call no event adapter design part in listview.

Comment: than in your listview xml file make some invisible views for no event and make condition in adapter if event is null than visible those view for no event. and hide event view.